# Android sync elements

Tags: android, android-studio

I am writing a budget tool in Android Studio to go with the board game Power Grid. I can get all these elements to function on their own, and I can create a method to have the program calculate the variables based on user input. What I can't do is get these elements to update automatically as each number is changed.

Specifically, how do I make the "Remainder" figure update as soon as the user enters their total funds, or taps one of the +/- buttons? How can I set limits on the buttons so they won't let the user allocate funds beyond what they have available?

[Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTbzs.jpg)

Apologies if this is already answered. I searched with every term I could think and found nothing.

Comment: The functions you are looking for are callbacks. For the `+` and `-` they would be button onClick events. and for the `EditText` it would be a `addTextChanged` listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ViewModels then you won't have this sync problem.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html